# Android Studio how to adjust the image source of a floating action button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the picture below , you can see 2 `FloatingActionButtons`. The one on the right is the default settings and the one on the left is the one I adjusted the size of the button. As you can see, the `srcCompat`, which is a plus sign, is not centered on the button. How to add padding or something to the `srcCompat` so that I can center it?

[image]

***Adjusted FButton***

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fBtn_scan"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="#286cd4"
            app:fabSize="auto"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="35dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

***Default FButton***

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="#286cd4"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `app:fabCustomSize="60dp"` instead of using `layout_height` and `layout_width` and the icon will be center as you wish.So use the default icon with width and height at *`wrap_contnet`* and just change the `app:fabCustomSize`  this is an exmaple :

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fBtn_scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#286cd4"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

Comment: I got it and it's working perfectly. Thank you very much maam/sir!!!!